# for each textbox in panel assign a different value from an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

i have a problem. I have an array and 20 textboxes on panel. i need to assign values from an array to textboxes. but the problem is that textboxes get a value of one number in each iteration. i tried to use `continue` and `break` to go to next iteration but it didnt give results.
Please, help me.

```
public void generator() 
    {
        int[] array = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (TextBox c in panel1.Controls)
            { 
                c.Text = array[i].ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

`getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20)` - this function generates an array from 1 to 80 and returns 20 numbers.

I would be grateful for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void generator() 
{
    int[] array = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        panel1.Controls[i].Text = array[i].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, it works. thanks. i will more attentive in future :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way-

```
public void generator() 
{
int[] array = getUniqueRandomArray(1, 81, 20).ToArray();
int i = 0;
foreach (TextBox c in panel1.Controls)
{ 
  c.Text = array[i].ToString();
  i++;
}
}
```

Comment: yes, it also works, but first way seems more effective